# Bootstrap - Set the Background of a Container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So for example the picture below I'm having typing giving each class="container" it's separate background colour/picture.

```
<div id="p" class="container">
</div>
```

style sheet

```
p.container {
     background-image: url(img/this_is_top.png) repeat;
}
```

CHANGING QUESTION for some reason I have having trouble in setting a background Image* for it.

[image]

Comment: Well fist of all you've got  "p" as an id so it should be `#p.container`.

Comment: Oh wow the simple things eh. thanks! Make it as you're answer

Comment: I changed the question, This seemed to work for color but not a background image.

Comment: I've just seen you comments now, glad you got your solution either way!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regarding your background image problem you currently have

```
background-image: url(img/this_is_top.png) repeat;
```

This is wrong. But you are thinking of the background shorthand CSS property which follows this syntax:

```
#p.container {background:#ffffff url('img/this_is_top.png') no-repeat center center;}
```

And if you are styling in your stylesheet and your folder hierarchy is the usual (/~/>/img etc) then it should be:

```
#p.container {
     background-image: #ffffff url('../img/this_is_top.png') repeat center center;
}
```

Notice the double dots before the url to tell CSS to look up a level for the img folder

Answer (score 4):

For starters, having multiple id's with the same name on the same page is not such a great idea. http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/